# If algorithm is derived from majorization-minimization, is it correct to measure error from the majorized form?

Tags: matrices, optimization, algorithms, matrix-decomposition

The main objective function for my non-negative matrix factorization (NMF) algorithm is [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) where the approximation of $V$ by $V \simeq WH$ is achieved by minimizing the error function $D(V ||WH)$.

$D(V ||WH)$ can be derived by majoriztion-minimization:

$D(V ||WH) \leq -\sum_{ij} V_{ij} \sum_{k} \pi_{ijk} log W_{ik} H_{kj} + \sum_{ij}(WH)_{ij} + const.    [1]$

where $V, W, H$ are matrices and the error can be calculated from the difference between $V$ and product of $WH$

And for regularization function for NMF, L1-norm can be majorized as:

$\Lambda \Omega(H_{s}) \leq \Lambda \sum_{g} \langle \frac{\hat{H}}{\epsilon + ||H_{g}||},H_{g} \rangle +const. [2]$

where $\Lambda$ is weight

The question is to measure the error from regularized function $[1] + [2]$, which functions I have to calculate the error from?

Is it the majorized form one: $-\sum_{ij} V_{ij} \sum_{k} \pi_{ijk} log W_{ik} H_{kj} + \sum_{ij}(WH)_{ij} + \Lambda \sum_{g} \langle \frac{\hat{H}}{\epsilon + ||H_{g}||},H_{g} \rangle$ (not $D(V ||WH) + \Lambda \Omega(H_{s})$ itself)? Or is there any techniques for this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "error"?  What quantity are you trying to determine.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I update my question. It is error between matrices $V$ and $WH$ of NMF using Kullback-Leibler Divergence.

Comment: Your question is still unclear.  In the MM method, you'll minimize the majorizing function and then compute the original objective function at that point.  The value that you care about is the original objective function.

Comment: @BrianBorchers So the majorizing function is only used because it is easier/better to be minimized like guarantees the minima. But the quality of algorithm is computed from the original objective function. Is this what you mean?

Comment: The quality of the *solution* is determined using the original objective function.